# Publishing Project's Distribution p12 Certificate file to public Github

Tags: xcode, security, github, public, p12

I initially distributed an xcode project (which is published to appstore too) using xcode version control. gitignore doesn't include p12 file extensions. thus the distribution p12 file to appstore is automatically published into Public Github.

is it normal and safe ? may cause a vulnerability?